# Rasterizing shapefiles using Geocube

Tags: python, rioxarray, geocube

I am trying to create a raster from a shapefile, with cells assigned a value from a specific column within the shapefile. I am using geocube below but am getting an error saying

> AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'rio'

```
vector_fn = 'C:\\Users\\LU_Imp_Polygon_Area.shp'

out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=vector_fn,
    measurements=["RC"],
    resolution=(-1, 1)
)
out_grid["RC"].rio.to_raster("C:\\Users\\my_rasterized_column.tif")
```

What does this error mean?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to `import rioxarray`.

https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/getting_started/getting_started.html